# dividing each column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a time series data 200*50
I want to take `(df.iloc[i+4]/df.iloc[i])-1` i.e. (5th row will be divided by the 1st row)-1, (6th row will be divided by 2nd row)-1 and so on for the entire dataframe.I am using below codes but getting this error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

```
for i in df:
  df1=[df[i+54]/df[i]]
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: `df.shift(-4).div(df) - 1`?

Answer (score 0):

If you print out

```
for i in df:
    print(i)
```

you'll see that you're just iterating over the columns in `df`.

If you want to stick with the for loop, you could do `for i in range(len(df)):`.

But you might be better suited by doing a [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) of 4 rows, like this:

```
df1 = df / df.shift(periods=-4) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but calculation is not correct. values are not matching